# how can i download ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

hello guys I want ubuntu 14.04. Anybody can give me a download link please? since in order to install one software named 'kalipetty' i need ubuntu 14.04. while installing on 17.04 it is showing ' your os is not supported'. please help

Answer (score 1):

Just choose the mirror nearest to you from [this page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) and download the Ubuntu version you want. I just checked, and Ubuntu 14.04 is available from the UK mirror (the one nearest to me).